# How to display artist's Alphabetic scroller in Music from iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, music, music.app

Before iOS 8.4 I had an Alphabet scroller to find artists quickly.
How to make it appear again?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the alphabetic scroller! Simply go in Music screen, select artist [image]

then scroll down to make "Most Recent" disappear and the scroller will appear again! [image]